# Question about analytic function at complex field

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

**Question: **

Is $f : C → C$ given by $f(z) = z^2 + z|z|^2$ differentiable at $z = 0$? If so, what is $f'(0)$?

Does $f^{n}(0)$ exist for $n ≥ 2$?

The first two questions are quite clear. It is differentiable at $z=0$ and $f'(0) = 0$

The problem is, I can't figure out how to approach the third part. The first approach of figuring out whether $f^{n}(0)$ exist for $n ≥ 2$ I thought was to figure out if $f$ is infinitely differentiable at points including $(0,0)$.

So I need to set an equation $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (f'(0+h) - f'(0))/h$.

However, as it is clear, $f(z)$ is not differentiable at point other than $(0,0)$($\because$  $|z|^2$ is only differentiable at $(0,0)$) so $f'(0+h)$ can not be defined, which makes that limit equation invalid.

Does that mean the answer for the third question is "$f^{n}(0)$ does not exists for $n≥2$"? Or is there some part that wrong on my approach such that $f^{n}(0)$ exists.

Comment: Hint: Can you think of a limit formula for higher order derivatives that only involves the original function?

Comment: I can think of such a formula - I don't see how it has any relevance to the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Your conclusion is indeed the right one.**

In order to speak of $f^{\prime\prime}(0)$, $f^\prime$ has to be defined in a neighborhood of $0$. As $z \mapsto z^2$ is holomorphic, $g^\prime(z)$ has to be defined in a neighborhood of $0$ where $g(z) = z \vert z \vert^2$.

But that can't be as if it was the case, $\frac{g(z)}{z}$ would be holomorphic for $z \neq 0$ which is not the case (it is a map taking only real values).

**Conclusion: $f^{\prime}$ is not defined in a neighborhood of zero and $f^{\prime\prime}(0)$ can't be defined. As well as obviously higher derivatives.**